# Django and radio buttons

Tags: django, radio-button

I am implementing a quiz app and I am displaying the multiple choice answers using radio buttons.

I need to group the answers per question, so I have it like this

```
{% for answer in quiz.quizanswer_set.all %}
<p><input type="radio" name="score[{{quiz.id}}]" value="{{answer.score}}"/>{{answer.answer}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

When I hit submit, I have the POST object like this

```
<QueryDict: {u'score[1]': [u'10'], u'score[3]': [u'10'], u'score[2]': [u'10'], u'Get Result': [u'Submit']}>
```

How do I loop through the scores in a canonical way?

I have tried `request.POST.getlist('score')` and it returns empty list

PS. the quiz.id may not in sequence, it's from the database row id.

My current work around is:

```
for quiz in Quiz.objects.all():
        total_score += int(request.POST.get('score[{0}]'.format(quiz.id)))
```

Comment: checkout the built-in [RadioSelect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) widget.

Comment: How does the RadioSelect widget will help me in this case?

Comment: I have the very same problem. Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Use the accepted answer's method, especially the list comprehension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just filter the POST keys:

```
for score_key in filter(lambda key:key.startswith('score'), request.POST.keys()):

    total_score += int(request.POST[score_key])
```

## Update

Thinking about it, a list comprehension would be better than filter:

```
for score_key in [key for key in request.POST.keys() if key.startswith('score[')]:

   total_score += int(request.POST[score_key])
```

## Update 2

Another way that I have been looking into, is keeping the name for each radio button the same (e.g. score) and then merging the quiz id with the value:

```
<input type="radio" name="score" value="{{quiz.id}}-{{answer.score}} />
```

You could then easily get a list of all scores and split the values:

```
for value in request.POST['score']:
    quiz_id, score = value.split('-')
```

Comment: I have just added another alternative, which may be preferable if there are lots of other input types on the page (would save on performing many .startswith calls).

Comment: wouldn't the same name would only allow me to choose one option across all questions?

Comment: Yes, you are right, update 2 wouldn't work with more than one question.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a PHP-ism by naming the inputs `score[{{quiz.id}}]`. Don't do that. Just call them all `score`, and your browser will do the right thing by putting them all in the same POST value which you can then get via `request.POST.getlist('score')`.

Comment: The problem is I need to group answers by different questions, how does single name will allow me to choose answers for different questions?